# EF code first schema generation problem

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, code-first

Why does this mapping (on SQL CE 4.0)

```
ToTable("USERS");
      HasKey(c => c.Id);
      Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("USERS_ID");
      Property(c => c.ActiveDirectoryUsername).HasColumnName("AD_ID");
      Property(c => c.LastUpdated).HasColumnName("LastUpdated").IsOptional();
      Property(c => c.Active).HasColumnName("Active").IsOptional();
      Property(c => c.AccountType).HasColumnName("AccountType").IsOptional();
      HasOptional(c => c.Contact).WithMany().Map(c => c.MapKey("CONTACT_ID"));
      Map<UserCompanyLink>(m => m.Requires("IsCompanyDelegate").HasValue(1));
      Map<UserDirectorLink>(m => m.Requires("IsCompanyDelegate").HasValue(0));
```

Generate this error

```
SetUp : System.InvalidOperationException : The database creation succeeded, but the creation of the database objects did not. See inner exception for more details.
  ----> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException : A column ID occurred more than once in the specification.
```

I would love to be able to see the schema sql being generated to debug this...

**edit**

Having added the IsCompanyDelegate to UserLink base entity, i now get

```
SetUp : System.Data.DataException : An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
  ----> System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException : An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
  ----> System.Data.MappingException : 
(69,10) : error 3023: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 69, 79, 88, 172:Column UserLink.IsCompanyDelegate has no default value and is not nullable. A column value is required to store entity data.
An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
  ((PK is NOT in 'UserLinks' EntitySet OR Entity is type [eServices.Admin.Data.Contexts.UserLink]) AND (PK is in 'UserLinks' EntitySet OR PK plays Role 'UserLink_Contact_Source' in AssociationSet 'UserLink_Contact'))
```

Utter cryptic gobbledygook.

Why is mapping TPH so damn complicated. the whole point of code first is to be able to create a model as you see fit?

**edit**

so it appears with no database existing, we get the first error (i.e. first test run), so the 2nd error is presumable irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a random error not related to this particular relationship.

I changed the connection from SQL Server CE to SQL Server 2008, and I was given a much more useful error message. This time it told me which column ID was and on which table.

Moral of the story, if you are using SQL Server CE, try its bigger brother, you might have more luck.